# Upgraded to Mongoose 5.12 and now I can't do findOneAndUpdate with $push operator

Tags: typescript, mongoose, push, findoneandupdate

I just upgraded to Mongoose 5.12 from 5.11 and am using Typescript.  I have this schema

```
const MyFileSchema = new Schema<IMyFile>({
    objectID: { type: String, required: true },
    attachments: { type: Array, required: false }
}, { collection: 'my_file' });
```

Now this findOneAndUpdate is suddenly failing to compile ...

```
await MyFile.findOneAndUpdate(
    { objectID },
    {
        $push: {
            attachments: { fileName: fileName, id: fileID },
        },
    },
);
```

complaining about ...

```
Type '{ attachments: { fileName: string; id: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'PushOperator<_AllowStringsForIds<LeanDocument<any>>>'.
Type '{ attachments: { fileName: string; id: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'NotAcceptedFields<_AllowStringsForIds<LeanDocument<any>>, readonly any[]>'.
Property 'attachments' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ fileName: string; id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

Is there another way to write the above to avoid this compilation error that wasn't happening when I was using Mongoose 5.11?

Comment: Seem like update mongoose to the lastest version will fix that error. Related issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10122

Comment: Or you can do something like: `$push: { attachments: { fileName: fileName, id: fileID }} as any`

Comment: Please paste a reproduction of the issue in something like https://codesandbox.io.

Comment: @Dave did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
await MyFile.findOneAndUpdate(
    objectID,
    {
      $push: {
        attachments: { fileName: fileName, id: fileID },
      },
    },
);
```

try with this It will work.

**Note**: You need to remove `{}` parenthesis from objectID search parameter.